# INSERT has more target columns than expressions - when using a SELECT query to insert into an empty table

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

The extraction table returns the below with a

```
SELECT * FROM track_raw LIMIT 5;

     title          |    artist     |     album     | album_id | count | rating | len
```

The table I want to input this data into looks like this;

```
id | title | len | rating | count | album_id
```

I'm using this line of code;

```
INSERT INTO track (title, len, rating, count, album_id) SELECT (title, len, rating, count, album_id) FROM track_raw;
```

For which I'm receiving the following error..

ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions

LINE 1: INSERT INTO track (title, len, rating, count, album_id) SELE...

So far I've been unable to identify why.

Comment: Remove the parentheses from `SELECT (title, len, rating, count, album_id)...`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parentheses around the `SELECT` list, so that the result becomes multiple columns rather than a single composite record.